# Knowing the MAC adress of a stolen laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, mac-address

Recently my HP 1000 laptop was stolen, is there any way to find its MAC address?

I connected my laptop to a PTCL EVO (Pakistan) WiFi USB dongle, but in the device options there is nothing I could find about the list of devices that have been connected some time ago.

Also 2 to 3 days ago I created a hotspot on the stolen laptop and connected another laptop to it.

Is there a way through which I can get MAC address from the laptop I connected to it?

Also 2 to 3 days ago I created a hotspot on my android phone and connected the stolen laptop, can the MAC address be retrieved from that mobile?

Comment: Any particular reason you would want to get the MAC address? Unless you were running some sort of non-standard verbose logging for connections on any of those devices, I doubt you will be able to get the mac address for the laptop from them.

Comment: My laptop logs the MAC address of every AP it has been connected to. Depending on what software you have installed on the other laptop, it may be logging such information as well. Mine is running Ubuntu and it logs the information in `/var/log/syslog`. A log entry with the MAC address could look like this: `Jun 29 13:42:59 dell kernel: [   37.813081] wlan0: authenticate with 12:99:47:6d:77:1a`

Comment: Some Wi-Fi routers retain information about devices that were recently connected. I'm not sure what a MAC address will really buy you though. Since they can be changed in software, I'm not sure it would stand up in court as a unique identifier to prove ownership. Aside from that, you could use it to locate the laptop but only if you're already in fairly close range.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't unless you have installed a monitor system that logs the network actions (remember anyway that the MAC address can be changed).

Comment: Thnx for reply :-(

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially retrieve the MAC address of you laptop form the following sources:

1. **ARP tables** of computers/switches (the mentioned laptop). As these get cleaned after a period of time, this will probably be difficult, but you may try.
2. **Logs from DHCP** services. If your address was assigned automatically it may be in the log.
3. As mentioned before, monitoring services like nVision, arping, arpscan, arpwatch, etc.
4. The log associated stations of the AP software if it has one.
5. Your vendor/supplier **might** have a list of MACs - S/Ns sold.

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer may keep records of the Mac address associated with your serial number - do you have a record of the S/N (on the original order for example)? Mac addresses are unique and there is a chance (technically they need to know in order to ensure uniqueness but whether they will give it to you is another matter!)